# Why Does raspi-config Depend On triggerhappy?

Tags: raspbian, raspi-config

As far as I can tell, triggerhappy is a daemon for handling custom input.  Since I have no direct use for this functionality (and there are no rules in /etc/triggerhappy/triggers.d/ by default) I want to remove it (for security/performance/OCD reasons).

But when I try to do so, apt-get removes raspi-config too, since its package depends on triggerhappy.

```
admin@rpi:/ $ sudo apt-get remove triggerhappy
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  raspi-config triggerhappy
...
Removing raspi-config (20160225) ...
Removing triggerhappy (0.3.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
admin@rpi:/ $
```

At first glace, this dependency doesn't make any sense to me.

Why does raspi-config depend on triggerhappy?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @Milliways I don't have a specific reason to remove it, other than I don't like having software I don't use running in the background.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Triggerhappy is only used in raspi-config's init script, see [line 17 of the init script](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/debian/raspi-config.init#L17). There it checks if any of the Shift keys is hold down at boot time to disable the ondemand scaling governor.

That means that `raspi-config` itself does not really need triggerhappy, just its boot up script. And the way that script uses `thd` doesn't seem to need the daemon running.

Comment: I've created a patch against `raspi-config` to make the dependency on `triggerhappy` optional and filed a [pull request for inclusion](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/pull/27)

Comment: Merged already. Wow! :-)

Comment: With the update of raspi-config released earlier this week, triggerhappy has been downgraded from `Depends` to `Recommends` and hence now can be uninstalled without issues. Now that went quick. :-)

Comment: where can I find list to tell which service is Depends or Recommends?

Comment: @bakalolo: Use `apt-cache show`, its output has lines starting with `Depends`, `Recommends` and `Suggests`, e.g. `apt-cache show triggerhappy | egrep 'Depends|Recommends|Suggests'`. Alternatively look on https://packages.debian.org/ for those packages which are used unmodified in Raspbian, too. (Actually most packages are, but not those coming from the archive.raspberrypi.org repo — these include `raspi-config` as it's coming from the Raspberry Pi Foundation and not from Debian.)